# Check if File Exists on Remote Machine via Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, remote-access

First - I am still relatively new to .net development. Now, since that's out of the way. I am making a reporting console application that will go and access remote machines and check to see if a certain .png exists on every machine and report if the image was there or if there was an error, and that error's message. I am reading in a CSV of IP addresses. Currently, my application will read the CSV into a list. Then, we iterate over the list appending the IP address to the beginning of a file path(i.e `\\10.155.191.239\c$\ProgramStuff\BlahBlah\StorePCMenu\Data\myAssets\App_Icons.png`). At the beginning of the console app, I elicit the user for credentials. I am using the .\desktop user credentials which should be sufficient for everything I am trying to do.

My problem > Application is reporting false negatives. Also, if a remote machine denies the credentials, it just shows me a generic error message and not a message pertaining to credentials denied.

We are currently using the PinvokeWindowsNetworking class to validate the credentials. However, I couldn't figure out how to get that class to report back whether or not the credentials were the actual problem. So, I included the ManagementScope class, which I was able for this to show me whether or not the credentials were validated (while using credentials other than .\desktop). However, this ManagementScope class does not seem to want to work with the .\desktop credentials.

```
foreach (myStruct record in myList)
{
    try
    {
        //ManagementScope myScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + record.myIP + "\\root\\cimv2", myOptions);
        ManagementScope myScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\"+ record.myIP + "\\", myOptions);
        myScope.Connect();
        if (myScope.IsConnected == true)
        {
            try
            {
                logEntry = PinvokeWindowsNetworking.connectToRemote("\\\\" + record.myIP, uName, pWord);
                if (File.Exists("\\\\" + record.myIP +eoPath ))
                {
                    output.WriteLine(record.store + " ," + record.myIP + ", yes");
                    Console.WriteLine(record.store + " ," + record.myIP + ", yes, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss"));
                }
                else if (!File.Exists(record.path))
                {
                    if (logEntry.Contains("Error"))
                    {
                        output.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + logEntry);
                        Console.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ", " + logEntry);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, File not found");
                        Console.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ", File not found");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ", " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        output.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(record.store + ", " + record.myIP + ", no, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") +", " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!logEntry.Contains("Error"))
        {
            PinvokeWindowsNetworking.disconnectRemote("\\\\" + record.myIP);
        }
    }
```

Any explanation of these two classes (other than MSDN links) or advice on which to use would be greatly appreciated! Would I need to open and close a socket between my client and all of these remote machines?

Comment: there were some security changes made in .net 4.0 vs how you could have done that back in .net 2.0-3.5 have code that would work however accessing network share remotely you probably won't have the access you need from your domain admin.. not to mention WMI on that particular server / machine is probably disabled.. also domain user account would need to be a service account which means Impersonation and that's a security issue / risk as well

Comment: It isn't very clear what your are complaining about, especially when you don't document the exception you get.  Do *not* assume you'll get a fine-grained diagnostic about an access denied condition, the operating system is not in the business of giving an attacker lots of information that will help him figure out his next attack attempt.  Do not use the administrative C$ share.  Do not use a local user account, whatever you use needs to be known on the target machine and have sufficient rights on that machine.  Using a domain controller is important.